# Windows Azure Local Blob Storage Access?

Tags: azure, local, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I don't understand why when I call :

LocalResource ls = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("mystorage");

ls.RootPath;

The local folder is not created, I don't understant how it works.
For me, it's a local path that is create. So I should have.

C:\Resources\directory\xxx.HelloAzureWeb.mystorage\

But there is not such file.

**Edit:**
What I am trying to do is to store some xml scene save files. In a Unity application, I need to post (save them) et get (use them) those files.

Comment: Will these XML will be created/edited/saved multiple times, when your  application is running? Or this will happen only once before the application start?

Comment: These XML will be edited several times during runtime as there are modifications on the scenes but only on important.

Comment: For this purpose, Local Storage is the best and it could give you the fast performance also but keep in mind that this storage is not persisted so if the VM goes down and reimage occur you will loose this data, unless you backup it to Azure Storage and then bring back when the VM restarts..

Comment: FYI, I have added one more answer to show how you can create files, write to it and then access it in any ASP.NET Web role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some misunderstanding you have about creating the local storage. When you call below code, it does not create Local Storage for you, instead it returns back to you an instance of Local Storage object which is created during Application setup:

```
LocalResource ls = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("mystorage");
```

To define local storage in your application you either directly add the following in CSDEF (below settings will create a local storage name mystorage, size 2GB and if any case VM is rebooted or role restarts, the local storage will not be clean and content still there:

```
<LocalResources>
 <LocalStorage cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" name="mystorage" sizeInMB="2048" />
</LocalResources>
```

To add local storage you can also choose ->> [ Visual studio > Role Properties > Local Storage > Add Local Storage ] option as well.

When you define Local Storage in your Windows Azure Application, a new folder will be added as below in your drive C: on Azure VM and this is done when you role is being provisioned in the VM during VM start time:

```
[In Azure VM]
C:\Resources\directory\[Your_deploymentID].[your_webrolename]_[Role_Instance_Count]\
```

```
[In Compute Emulator]
// Lunch your application in Compute Emulator and then open "Compute Emulator UI" to see the Local Storage Path in the command window related to your instance:
C:\Users\avkashc\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\3503509c-2112-45ea-8d63-377fe9f78491\directory\mystorage\
```

Once you will add above local storage specific settings in ServiceDefinition.CSDEF, your local storage will be created and then the following code will work:

```
LocalResource ls = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("mystorage");
ls.Root // returns the correct local storage path
// Now you can use ls to read/write your data.
```

Comment: Ok that's what I thought. But i come back to my previous question. How can I send a local xml file to my page and then store it in the blob storage. I am totally lost concerning blob storage. The problem is that i need to get the file in my web page and as you explained there is no way to get it with a path for exemple. But it's possible with a html submit maybe i can "emulate" this behaviour ?

Comment: Do one thing please. Write your objective without using any blob or local storage or anything. Just in simple sentence please provide your problem and then I can suggest what would be the best from my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the files I store to the storage emulator blobs go into `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\DevelopmentStorage\LDB\BlockBlobRoot`. Unfortunately, they're not very useful. It's just a bunch of GUIDs, but the filesizes look correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is how you access Local Storage in your ASP.NET Web Role:**

Step 1: Created a very simple ASP.NET Web Role Project

Step 2: Included the following in servicedefinition.csdef:

```
<LocalResources>
 <LocalStorage name="mystorage" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" sizeInMB="2096" />
</LocalResources>
```

Step 3: Add the following code in any aspx (in this case about.aspx)

```
<div>
  Local Storage file content: <b><asp:Label ID="fileContent" runat="server" /></b>
</div>
```

Step 4: Add the following code in any aspx.cs  (in this case about.aspx.cs):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        LocalResource myStorage = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("mystorage");
        string filePath = Path.Combine(myStorage.RootPath, "Lesson.txt");
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, "First Lesson");
        fileContent.Text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

}
```

That's it. 
I have tested this code in compute emulator and on Cloud and it does work.

Comment: There's no probleme about using and writing in the local storage. The problem is that I have data (a xml file) on my local computer and I want to store it on the windows cloud service. The Questions is, how to transfert this data without any forms or whatever. I thought passing the local path of my file on a .net page and do a blob.createfile(path) but there is no link because it uses the vm path.

Comment: When u say you want to "store on windows cloud service", do u mean at Windows Azure VM or at Windows Azure Storage? IF you want your file to be part of Windows Azure VM you need to add it part of your Azure app and set "copy local as true". IF you want to transfer this file to Azure blob storage, you can use 3rd party tools i.e. http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-microsoft-azure-explorer.aspx or CloudXprorer..

Comment: I found a way to achieve my goal there is no more problem I just send the xml data to an asp.net controller and store it in the azure storage as a xml blob. Thanks for your help and your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

When using the storage emulator, Local Resource allocation is just a file directory. The root path looks a bit different from what you describe, but you should be able to navigate to that directory on your local machine, which will initially be empty. You *should* be seeing it under your \users\you\AppData (which is a hidden directory).

Oh, and local resources have nothing to do with Blob storage. In Windows Azure, it's just a locally-attached disk resource with a specific size quota. It's non-durable storage, unlike Blob storage. Perfect for temporary file writes, caching, etc. and faster than Blob Storage since it's a local disk, but for anything that needs to persist, you'll want to consider Blobs.

Comment: Thanks for your precisions. But the path you describe is when you test your stuff with visual. When you publish your work the path is like is discribed it.

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood, as the question was a bit tough to read. Yes, different directory structure in Windows Azure, but effectively the same thing. Once you get the root location, you are free to read and write to that location, up to the quota you set up.